# Oracle Insert Multiple Value Shows Error Message

Tags: insert, oracle11g, sqldatetime

```
INSERT ALL
into instructor values (
835, 'SPARKS', 4000 , 200, 978, '16-12-1984')

into instructor values (
978, 'STEEL', 5000 , 250, 222, '16-01-1980')
```

and it was:

```
INSERT ALL
into instructor values (
835, 'SPARKS', 4000 , 200, 978, '16-DEC-1984')

into instructor values (
978, 'STEEL', 5000 , 250, 222, '16-JAN-1980')
```

The table EXISTS and SETUP CORRECTLY.
Error message shows ORA-01843: not a valid month.
Where did I do it wrong?

Thank you

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107900/ora-01843-not-a-valid-month). Might be helpful. Also [see this](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01843.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're giving a **string** for a **DATE** type column.

In cases like this, Oracle implicitly converts the string to a date according to `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` - see this [sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bca90/4)

The right way to do that is either as [Valex suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15476548/1083652) or like this:

```
INSERT ALL
into instructor values (
835, 'SPARKS', 4000 , 200, 978,date '1984-12-16')
into instructor values (
978, 'STEEL', 5000 , 250, 222, date '1980-01-16')
SELECT * from DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1):

use month as a 3 letter character not a number instead of 12 use dec

Answer (score 1):

Just use [TO_DATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) to convert string into date

```
INSERT ALL
into instructor values (
835, 'SPARKS', 4000 , 200, 978,TO_DATE('16-12-1984','DD-MM-YYYY'))
into instructor values (
978, 'STEEL', 5000 , 250, 222,TO_DATE('16-01-1980','DD-MM-YYYY'))
SELECT * from DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yor are trying to insert DATE without mentioning the format, so oracle is using its default DATE fromat which `DD-MON-YYYY`

You can try on the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/01009/10/0)

Comment: That's not accurate, Oracle Date doesn't have a format, nor a difault one. The problem is that he's giving a string instead of a date so oracle must convert it. For this it uses the NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter (which AFAIK does have a default value as you mentioned)